# Nested Array list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am asking user candidate info then i am calling 'addcandidate' method  and i am trying to hold candidate info in array list.By the way  if user want to add new candidate  i am  getting   again their info and want to add  my arraylist.But its holding only  last  candidate info

my addcandidate method  code like this

```
static  void addcandidate(String name,String surname,String adress,String talent){
    List<List<Object>>listoflist=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object>candidatelist=new ArrayList<Object>();
    candidatelist.add(name);
    candidatelist.add(surname);
    candidatelist.add(adress);
    candidatelist.add(talent);
    listoflist.add(candidatelist);
    

    System.out.println(listoflist);

}
```

and also mycode that to ask candidate info like that

```
  while (true){
        Scanner oku=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("what kind of process do you want ? 1-Add Candidate 2-Add Employee " +
                "3- add employee from candidate 4-search candidate for talent 5-print wiew");
        int processtype=oku.nextInt();

        if (processtype==1){
            System.out.println("please enter candidate name");
            String cname=oku.next();
            System.out.println("please enter candidate sname");
            String csname=oku.next();
            System.out.println("please enter candidate adress");
            String cadress=oku.next();
            System.out.println("please enter candidate talent");
            String ctalent=oku.next();
            Candidate.addcandidate(cname,csname,cadress,ctalent);
            System.out.println("do you want to continue");
            String answer=oku.next();
            if (answer=="n"){
                break;
            }


        }
    }
```

my output expectation  is like this [[tom,jhn,usa,it],[peter,parker,england,language]]

Comment: listOflist is only stored in a local variable in addcandidate, and you create a new list each time you call addcandidate.

Comment: thank you for your answer but how can i create new list each time call addcandidate can you  give example please

Comment: I mean that's what you are doing at the moment. You need to add the candidates to a list whose lifetime is the same as your entire program.

Comment: Use class to store per candidate info

Answer (score 2):

You need declare `listoflist` out of method `addcandidate`. For example like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static List<List<Object>> listoflist = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addcandidate("Name 1", "Surname 1", "Street 1", "Music");
        addcandidate("Name 2", "Surname 2", "Street 2", "Singing");
        addcandidate("Name 3", "Surname 3", "Street 3", "Sport");
    }

    public static void addcandidate(String name, String surname, String adress, String talent){
        List<Object> candidatelist = new ArrayList<Object>();
        candidatelist.add(name);
        candidatelist.add(surname);
        candidatelist.add(adress);
        candidatelist.add(talent);
        listoflist.add(candidatelist);


        System.out.println(listoflist);

    }
}
```

The result of executing this code.

```
[[Name 1, Surname 1, Street 1, Music]]
[[Name 1, Surname 1, Street 1, Music], [Name 2, Surname 2, Street 2, Singing]]
[[Name 1, Surname 1, Street 1, Music], [Name 2, Surname 2, Street 2, Singing], [Name 3, Surname 3, Street 3, Sport]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much very good it's working I appreciate

Comment: @BasitAnlat Welcome, I'm glad to hear that my answer was useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your `listoflist` declaration is inside `addCandiadte` method so each time the array list is being created and finally you are having the list that was created last. Do something like below:

```
// outside addCandiadte method
 List<List<Object>>listoflist=new ArrayList<>();

static  void addcandidate(String name,String surname,String adress,String talent){
   
    List<Object>candidatelist = new ArrayList<Object>();    
    
    candidatelist.add(name);
    candidatelist.add(surname);
    candidatelist.add(adress);
    candidatelist.add(talent);
    
    listoflist.add(candidatelist);
    

    System.out.println(listoflist);

}
```

Hope you got the point.
Additionally use `List<String>candidatelist` instead of `List<Object>candidatelist` for better readability and type checking.

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate all of you

Comment: Hi @Basit Anlat, glad to help you. Please "Accept"  one answer so that it will help other readers on SO. You can also vote multiple answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers